# something goes wrong with my ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It seem doesn't want to render.

http://plnkr.co/edit/IoymnpSUtsleH1pXgwFj

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.lists = [
    {"name": "a"},
    { "name": "b"},
     {"name" :"c"}
  ];
});
```

html

```
<li ng-repeat="item in lists">
  <span>item.name</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `{{ }}` symbol as following:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in lists">
  <span> {{ item.name }}</span>
</li>
```